# Is it possible to get the ip addresses of instances in a load balancer?

Tags: linux, dns

when I run `dig mydomain.com all` there's only 1 A record in the answer section which is the wan ip of the load balancer.

There are a few instances in this load balancer

Is there any way I can get a complete list of all the ip addresses of the instances managed by the load balancer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is not possible to get this info from DNS, so you must ask the load balance itself. load balancing is supposed to be invisible to the client so this is by design. load balancers usually work at the service level to redirect to the balanced nodes service implementation as needed, so there is no IP layer magic that would answer that question.